# VS Code auto-incorrecting getServerSideProps type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

There is a setting in my VS Code somewhere that is automatically change my types when `getServerSideProps` is present in code. It replaces my types with a generic type, which then breaks all the type checks in the file. I have to edit in vi in order to bypass the vs code overwrite.

`const Account = ({user}: AccountProps)`

When I save the file, it gets automagically changed to

`const Account = ({user}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>)`

Like so:

[image: Naughty VS Code]

I tried disabling every single extension I have installed, including ESLint, Prettier, various [Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) extensions, etc. No effect. I searched for variations 'getServerSideProps' throughout my User Preferences, didn't find anything. I don't have eslintrc.json present, but here's my ts config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

What is autocorrecting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the `Prisma NextJS` extension installed.